# Filtering for null values of another column with null values for sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum a column value, but not include rows from another columns that have null values how can I filter for those out? if one of updated_time or saved_time is NULL then I don't want to include that amount in my sum

```
id | amount | updated_time     |      saved_time
4     444       Null              2017-07-20 12:05:04
4     22   2017-07-20 12:05:09   2021-07-20 11:01:06
4     100       Null                     NULL
5     43        Null              2017-07-20 12:05:09
5     500   2018-07-20 05:05:09   2017-07-20 12:05:44
7     3500  2018-07-20 05:05:09           Null
7     4500  2018-01-20 02:02:02   2018-07-20 12:23:23
7     1500  2020-02-20 02:05:09   2017-07-20 12:05:44
```

I only want to sum rows 2, 5, 6 and 7 for ex.

Comment: Using a mere where clause? `select sum(amount) from mytable where updated_time is not null and saved_time is not null`?

Comment: I only want to filter out if either or not both

Comment: Oh, that's special :-D `select sum(amount) from mytable where (updated_time is not null and saved_time is null) or (updated_time is null and saved_time is not null)`.

Comment: doesn't give me right output weird

Comment: seems to be omitting many rows

Comment: Oops, I got it vice versa. According to your explanation you'll want `select sum(amount) from mytable where (updated_time is not null and saved_time is not null) or (updated_time is null and saved_time is null)`.

Comment: that would just give me if they are both null or not null? It can be either or

Comment: You want to exclude rows where updated_time is null, but saved_time isn't. And you want to exclude rows where saved_time is null, but updated_time isn't. In other words: You only want to include the rows where both values are not null or both values are null.

Comment: No sorry I meant if either column is null I dont want to include that row in my sum so only if both are not null would it be included

Comment: You only want to include rows where neither is null? As shown in my very first query above? Why did you say this is not what you want?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In your request comments you have clarified that you want an exclusive or. You want to consider the rows where either both times are set or both times are not set, i.e. exclude the rows where exactly one of the times is not set.

Use an appropriate combination of `IS NULL`, `AND`, and `OR` for this. The straight-forward option:

```
select sum(amount)
from mytable
where (updated_time is not null and saved_time is not null) 
  or  (updated_time is     null and saved_time is     null);
```

If you alreay have a where clause, make sure to put these conditions into parentheses:

```
select sum(amount)
from mytable
where <existing conditions>
  and
  (
       (updated_time is not null and saved_time is not null) 
    or (updated_time is     null and saved_time is     null)
  );
```

If you want to apply the condition only to this one sum and have other aggregations independent, then move the conditions into your aggregation function (`SUM`):

```
select
  sum(amount) as total,
  sum(case when (updated_time is not null and saved_time is not null) 
             or (updated_time is     null and saved_time is     null)
        then amount else 0 end) as filtered
from mytable
where <existing conditions>;
```